# How to verify that the XCM message went through successfully?

Tags: xcmp, parity-bridges-common, bridge

I am currently bridging the tokens from one `Parachain` to another, and I am examining two events to ensure the successful completion of the transaction. The first event is `xcmpQueue.Success`, which occurs on the destination chain, while the second event is `xcmpQueue.XcmpMessageSent`, which takes place on the chain from which I am bridging the tokens.

Both of these events provide a `messageHash` that I can compare to establish a connection between the two events and verify the successful execution of the transaction.

However, this approach requires me to maintain connections with both chains, which may be unnecessary. I am considering an alternative solution to address this concern.

In the block where the XCM message is received, I can examine the `parachainSystem.setValidationData` extrinsic and inspect the `downwardMessages`. Here is an example of what I observed:

```rs
{
  ...
  2001: [
    {
      sentAt: 18,066,095
      data: 0x000210010400010200451f06080001000700e87648170a1300010200451f06080001000700e8764817010220bcbe0d01000400010100d8a1107cf72bacdb288d6fd9af62dc85988f267043c4958821b215a24055706d
    }
  ]
  ...
}
```

Although I am unsure about the specific contents of the data, my assumption is that it could be used to compute the same hash as in the `xcmpQueue.Success` event. Hence, my question is twofold: How can I decode the data field, or is there an entirely different approach that would allow me to achieve my intended outcome?

I would greatly appreciate any assistance or guidance you can provide. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Great question! As you probably know, one of the properties of XCM is that it is asymmetric - so you fire away and there is no guarantee of results.

That being said, you can use the following instructions:

- `ReportHolding`
- `QueryPallet`
- `ReportError`
- `ReportTransactStatus`

Each of these instructions include a `QueryResponseInfo` struct:

```rust
pub struct QueryResponseInfo {
    pub destination: MultiLocation,
    #[codec(compact)]
    pub query_id: QueryId,
    pub max_weight: Weight,
}
```

The consensus system that receives this instruction would execute the instruction that includes the `QueryResponseInfo` and send a corresponding `QueryResponse`:

```rust
QueryResponse {
    #[codec(compact)]
    query_id: QueryId,
    response: Response,
    max_weight: Weight,
    querier: Option<MultiLocation>,
}

// Reponse Struct
pub enum Response {
    /// No response. Serves as a neutral default.
    Null,
    /// Some assets.
    Assets(MultiAssets),
    /// The outcome of an XCM instruction.
    ExecutionResult(Option<(u32, Error)>),
    /// An XCM version.
    Version(super::Version),
    /// The index, instance name, pallet name and version of some pallets.
    PalletsInfo(BoundedVec<PalletInfo, MaxPalletsInfo>),
    /// The status of a dispatch attempt using `Transact`.
    DispatchResult(MaybeErrorCode),
}
```

A lot more on this subject is written here:

- https://paritytech.github.io/xcm-docs/journey/queries.html

with some concrete examples here:

- https://github.com/paritytech/xcm-docs/blob/main/examples/src/8_queries/mod.rs

You may also be interested in the `Expect` instructions:

- https://paritytech.github.io/xcm-docs/journey/expects.html